# Managing the output of logstash pipelines

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

We're trying to add a field for all pipelines in a `LogStash` server (we have 6 on-premise logstash, 3 in each country).
In specific we're trying to add a field from environment variables to mark the output of a pipeline with a suffix in the index, for example (us, eu), but we have many pipelines (approximately 145 by country) and the main idea isn't adding this environment variable in all outputs plugins, also that is not mandatory so if someone forgets to add the environment variable we'll have serious problems.

Then, we're trying to find a method to add this field automatically in each output without add this environment variable, in your experience is it possible in logstash "world" attach a suffix in an index in an output plugin?

example

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => localhost
    manage_template => false
    index => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}_${COUNTRY_VARIABLE}"
  }
}
```

I want to add `${COUNTRY_VARIABLE}` automatically before sending the document.

It's not possible to do this in `elasticsearch` because that is mounted in `aws` and the traffic to check all possible hosts inputs from `logstash` is a cost that we don't want to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this will work. If you add a fallback value to the env var, you're fine in the case someone forgot to define one: `${COUTRY_VARIABLE:XX}`

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => localhost
    manage_template => false
    index => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}_${COUNTRY_VARIABLE:ABC}"
  }
}
```

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) for more background on env vars in logstash.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is not the correct answer because I'm talking about a method to add this variable without edit each pipeline file.